# random_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to generate 6 random transformations for images with the `random_transform` method from tensorflow. Here is my code:

```
train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(
                               train_dir, 
                               target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                               color_mode='rgb',
                               classes=None, 
                               class_mode='categorical', 
                               batch_size=128, 
                               shuffle='True', 
                               seed=None, 
                               save_to_dir=None, 
                               save_prefix='', 
                               save_format='png', 
                               follow_links=False, 
                               subset=None, 
                               interpolation="nearest")
train_image_generator = train_image_generator.random_transform(
                                              train_data_gen[0][0][0], 
                                              seed=None)
```

I get the following error:

```
random_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

My `train_data_gen[0][0][0]` is a 3D array - I don't know where my mistake is.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am new. I changed the code and hope it is now better to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`random_transform` is a method of `ImageDataGenerator` objects.  So, you'll need something LIKE:

```
train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator()
train_image_generator.random_transform(train_data_gen[0][0][0], seed=None)
```

Comment: I have it - you can see it in my third code snippet. ```train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)```